# NgbDatePicker doesn't format Date correctly using NgbDateParserFormatter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Unfortunately having some issues with this trivial task, but it seems this is a recommended way of formating the date in a input field, using this ParserFormater. When a user chooses the date from the calendar, the date is shown correctly in the input field box, in 'dd-MM-yyyy' format (as I want), but when I save the details into a database the date is being returned back in some weird format and it's not even correct. I get something like this: '1907-02-09T00:00:00'......here is the front end code below if someone can point me in the right direction:

```
//html
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="motDate">MOT Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"
               ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (focus)="d.open()" (dateSelect)="onMOTDateSelected($event)" #motDate>
        <input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="model.motDate" name="motDate"/>
      </div>

//typescript
export class AppComponent {
  model: Vehicle = <Vehicle>{};

  @ViewChild('motDate') motDatePicker;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.motDatePicker.nativeElement.value = this.model.motDate;
  }

  onMOTDateSelected(e) {
    console.log("MOT Date Selected");
    this.model.motDate = new Date(e.day, e.month, e.year);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class NgbDateCustomParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {
  parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
    if (value) {
      const dateParts = value.trim().split("/");
      if (dateParts.length === 1 && isNumber(dateParts[0])) {
        return { day: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: null, year: null };
      } else if (dateParts.length === 2 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1])) {
        return {
          day: toInteger(dateParts[0]),
          month: toInteger(dateParts[1]),
          year: null
        };
      } else if (dateParts.length === 3 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1]) && isNumber(dateParts[2])) {
        return {
          day: toInteger(dateParts[0]),
          month: toInteger(dateParts[1]),
          year: toInteger(dateParts[2])
        };
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
    return date ? `${isNumber(date.day) ? padNumber(date.day) : `""}/${isNumber(date.month) ? padNumber(date.month) : ""}/${date.year}` : "";`
  }
}

export function toInteger(value: any): number {
  return parseInt(`${value}`, 10);
}

export function isNumber(value: any): value is number {
  return !isNaN(toInteger(value));
}

export function padNumber(value: number) {
  if (isNumber(value)) {
    return `0${value}`.slice(-2);
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

// vehicle model
export interface Vehicle {
  motDate: Date;
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe recreate your error in a stackblitz or jsfiddle? It would be a lot easier to help then. One thing that looks a bit off is that in your parse method, which should convert the input string into the NgbDateStruct which should be the object returned, there is a ```split(/)``` but you don't have any slashes inside the input format of your date. What is the result of the parse method when you enter a date?

Comment: There is no error to recreate at the moment. The date that is being returned from the database and which is initialized on ngOnInit looks like this: ''1907-02-09T00:00:00', instead of eg. '29/07/2019'....so my guess is there is something going wrong on formatting model value 'motDate', but can't figure out why. As for the parser, I used the one found on this discussion: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2072         I noticed some other plugins just have a simple displayFormat option, but can't use anything else as my senior dev suggested, but isn't willing to help out.

Comment: But I would assume that the date format you are receiving from the database is not going to change. So what you really need in the first place is a service or a method inside your component which converts your database date model into your view date model  Which needs to be of type NgbDateStruct. And then you need the CustomFormatter which converts from NgbDateStruct to String and back. And whenever you want to send the date back to the server you need to convert it back into the right form the server accepts.

Answer (score 0):

Zokes, NgbDate NgbDateStruct interface as a model and not the native Date unless you use as provider NgbDateNateiveAdapter or NgbDateNativeUTCAdapter

```
providers: [{provide: NgbDateAdapter, useClass: NgbDateNativeAdapter}]
```

So you need decided if you want work with elements {year:...,month:...,dat:...} or with objects Date of javascript.

You normally store the data in a dbs using a string or using an Object Date (or DateTime), and you received in the same way. So I like transform the dates in the own service. Imagine that you received in your service data with a propertie "date"

```
getData(key:any)
{
     this.get(...).pipe(map((response)=>{
        let parts=response.date.split('T')[0].split('-')
        response.date={year:+parts[0],month:+parts[1],day:+parts[2]}
        return response;
     }
     ))
}
getList(key:any)
{
     this.get(...).pipe(map((response:any[])=>{
        response.forEach(x=>{
         let parts=x.date.split('T')[0].split('-')
         x.date={year:+parts[0],month:+parts[1],day:+parts[2]}
        })
        return response;
     }
     ))
}
updateData(data)
{
    data.date=data.year+"-"+data.month+"-"+data.day
    this.http.post(....,data)
}
```