# Get Dates from C# API to Angular for ngx-bootstrap DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, angular, ngx-bootstrap

For using Angular's ***ngx-bootstrap datepicker*** Disabled days for the calendar I have a controller on C#

```
public List<DateTime> DisabledDays(int carId)
{
    var disabledDates = new List<DateTime>();
    var result = GetAll();
    var startResult = _rentalDal.GetAll().Where(x => x.CarId == carId).Select(x => x.RentDate).ToList();
    var endResult = _rentalDal.GetAll().Where(x => x.CarId == carId).Select(x => x.ReturnDate).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Data.Count; i++)
    {
        //for (var disDate = startResult[i]; disDate <= endResult[i]; disDate = DateTime.Parse(disDate.AddDays(1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
        for (var disDate = startResult[i]; disDate <= endResult[i]; disDate = disDate.AddDays(1))
        {
            disabledDates.Add(DateTime.Parse(disDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")));
            //disabledDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(disDate)).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
            //disabledDatesString.Add(dt.(ToString("d MMM YY")));
        }
    }

    return disabledDates;
}
```

it's working ok but the format should be like YYYY-MM-DD I tried something but couldn't put output for Angular needed. My Output is

```
    "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
    "2021-01-02T00:00:00",
    "2021-01-03T00:00:00",
    "2021-01-04T00:00:00",
    "2021-01-05T00:00:00",
    "2021-01-06T00:00:00",
    "2021-01-07T00:00:00",
    "2021-01-08T00:00:00",
    "2021-01-09T00:00:00",
    "2021-01-10T00:00:00",
```

angulars method works when I put this manuely it works but when I tried to get it with a function its receiving data like above.

```
    disabledDates: Date[];
    
    this.disabledDates = [
          new Date('2021-03-20'),
          new Date('2021-03-10'),
          new Date('2021-03-11'),
        ];

getDisabledDates(carId:number){
   this.rentalService.getDisabledDates(carId).subscribe(response=>{
    this.disabledDates= response
     console.log(response)
   })
```

is there a way to get my date format like YYYY-MM-DD like disabledDates manual feed? and the second one is this new Date simply added by a for or for each loop

Comment: I would leave the c# code as is and change the javascript function to format received values from the backend as needed. You could use a `map` function on the Array and then either do a string function like `substring(0,10)` or use date manipulation by parsing and then reformatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `startResult` and `endResult` variables are `List<DateTime>` then the modified method will definitely work for you.

So, you don't need to `List<string>` as your method's return type instead of `List<DateTime>`.

Because at your JSON response both `DateTime` and `string` will be `string`.

**Solution:**

```
public List<string> DisabledDays(int carId)
{
    var disabledDates = new List<string>();
    var result = GetAll();
    var startResult = _rentalDal.GetAll().Where(x => x.CarId == carId).Select(x => x.RentDate).ToList();
    var endResult = _rentalDal.GetAll().Where(x => x.CarId == carId).Select(x => x.ReturnDate).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Data.Count; i++)
    {
        for (var disDate = startResult[i]; disDate <= endResult[i]; disDate = disDate.AddDays(1))
        {
            disabledDates.Add(disDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }
    }

    return disabledDates;
}
```

Comment: thats ok but when trying to return it CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>'

Comment: Maybe you forgot to change the return type of your method.

Comment: exactly. that worked thank you for help. Just marged result startresult and end result with linq select new.

Answer (score 1):

I like the service was who transform the dates. in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57254564/ngbdatepicker-doesnt-format-date-correctly-using-ngbdateparserformatter/57259183#57259183) transform the dates from string to ngbDate, the same to transform in Date Object -imagine your property is "date"

```
getData(key:any)
{
     this.get(...).pipe(map((response)=>{
        response.date=new Date(response.date)
        return response;
     }
     ))
}
getList(key:any)
{
     this.get(...).pipe(map((response:any[])=>{
        response.forEach(x=>{
         x.date=new Date(x.date)
        })
        return response;
     }
     ))
}
updateData(data2)
{
    //see that in this case you make a copy of the object
    const data={...data2,date:data2.date.getFullYear()+"-"+
                  ('00'+(data2.date.getMonth()+1).slice(-2)+'-'+
                  ('00'+date.getDate()).slice(-2)
               }
    this.http.post(....,data)
}
```

So, in your component you work always with date object